# How can I run chruby with Ansible?

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, ansible, chruby

I developed an [Ansible role](https://galaxy.ansible.com/ferrarimarco/chruby/) that installs chruby and [another one](https://galaxy.ansible.com/ferrarimarco/ruby/) that installs ruby using ruby-install.

I would like to use chruby in my Ansible playbooks, but the `chruby` command is not available to the `command` and `shell` modules, even if chruby works fine if I login via SSH with the same user I am running the playbook with.

This is what I tried:

1. Ensuring that chruby is available to all users by deploying the following script to `/etc/profile.d/chruby.sh`, as suggested in [chruby's README](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby#system-wide):

   ```
   if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] || [ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ]; then
     source /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh
     source /usr/local/share/chruby/auto.sh
   fi
   ```
2. Running a task with the `command` or `shell` modules (using `/bin/bash` as executable) to manually run `source /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh` and `source /usr/local/share/chruby/auto.sh` before executing a `command` task for `chruby`

In both cases I got the following error: `chruby: command not found`.

**How can I run chruby within an Ansible play?**

Comment: Would you please try to set the `PATH` environment? You can check the FAQ (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html).

Comment: Yes, but it defeats the purpose of chruby I believe...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write simple bash/etc script or you can source those files:

```
shell: bash -c "source /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh; source /usr/local/share/chruby/auto.sh;chruby ..."
```